# Reinitialise jQuery dataTable after AJAX processing

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am attempting to reload my dataTable after a simple delete Ajax process. So basically on the page load the dataTable gets initialised and works great as I need. In the table I have a button which allows me to delete a specific entry(row). After clicking this button, I process this delete function using the AJAX and then on the success of the function I reload my table with the updated Data having my deleted row gone from the table. Although, when this function gets instantiated, my table looses the jQuery dataTable functionalities, and returns to a normal table.

This is my ajax call for DELETING a row:

```
var oTable = $(".all_sightings_table").dataTable({
        "sDom": "<'row'<''l><''f>r>t<'row'<''i><''p>>"
    }); 

    function reinitialiseTable() {
        $(".all_sightings_table").dataTable();
    }



$(document).on("click", ".delete_sighting", function() {
        if(oTable != undefined) {
            oTable.fnClearTable();
        }
        var id = +$(this).val();
        reset();
        $("#toggleCSS").attr("href", "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/style/alertify.bootstrap.css");
        alertify.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this sighting?", function(e) {
            if(e) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteSighting/" + id,
                    type: "DELETE",
                    success: function(result) {
                        $(".all_sightings_container").load("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/dashboard #all_sightings_table"); // reload table after processess
                        $(".sightings_container").load("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/userSightings #sightings_table");
                        alertify.success("You have succesfully deleted the sighting");
                        reinitialiseTable(); // attempting to reintialise dataTable 
                    } 
                }); 
            } else {
                alertify.error("Operation has been cancelled");
            }
        });
    }); // end of function
```

So I attempt to call my function to reinitialise my dataTable, although it fails and does not work. This is the table I am attempting to reinitialise:

```
<!-- All sightings container -->    
                            <div class="all_sightings_container table-responsive">
                                <table id="all_sightings_table" class="all_sightings_table table table-hover table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr class="active">
                                            <td>Sighting ID:</td>
                                            <td>Park of Sighting:</td>
                                            <td>Location in Park:</td>
                                            <td>Pest Name:</td>
                                            <td>Total Pest's Sighted:</td>
                                            <td>Sighted Date:</td>
                                            <td>Submitted by:</td>
                                            <td>Additional Information:</td>
                                            <sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_STAFF')">
                                                <td>View all by User:</td>
                                                <td>Delete:</td>
                                            </sec:authorize>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <c:forEach var="sighting" items="${sightings}">
                                            <tr>
                                                    <td><c:out value="${sighting.id}"/></td>
                                                    <td><c:out value="${sighting.park}"/></td>
                                                    <td><c:out value="${sighting.location}"/></td>
                                                    <td><c:out value="${sighting.pest_name}"/></td>
                                                    <td><c:out value="${sighting.total_pests}"/></td>
                                                    <td><c:out value="${sighting.date}"/></td>
                                                    <td><c:out value="${sighting.username}"/></td>
                                                    <td><c:out value="${sighting.information}"/></td>
                                                    <sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_STAFF')">
                                                        <td>
                                                            <a class="sighting" href="<c:url value="/userSightings"><c:param name="username" value="${sighting.username}"/></c:url>"><button class="btn btn-success">User Sightings</button></a>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <button class="delete_sighting btn btn-danger" value="${sighting.id}">Delete Sighting</button>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </sec:authorize>
                                                </tr>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                    </tbody>
                                    </table>
```

I have tried using the functions fnDraw() and others, but still no luck.
All answer are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: before reinitialise you should clear the table using if (oTable != undefined) {
    oTable.fnClearTable();
};

Answer (score 0):

Intailize The Table

```
var oTable = $(".all_sightings_table").dataTable();
```

Clearing The Old Table

```
if (oTable != undefined) { 
oTable.fnClearTable(); 
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where do I place the if statement? Within the success function of the Ajax?

Comment: no whenever you call ajax function or above ajx function you put it will clear old table and add new datas to the table if it works accept as answer

Comment: I've tried implementing this, although no luck. I have updated my question with the implementation. Check if it is correct.

Comment: remove this function reinitialiseTable(); and calls in script

Comment: Just call oTable.fnDraw();

Comment: That does not work. I have already tried. I think the $().load(${pageContext.request.contextPath}/); overwrites it.